# Expressing a complex structure in Terraform and reading it in Go

Tags: go, terraform

Note: edited after a comment from @JimB

I am trying to build a new Terraform provider in Go. The resource that I need is a bit complex. It includes structures, arrays within structures, arrays and structures within arrays. When I run Terraform, it gives me errors, for example:
`panic: Error reading level config: '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type 'map[string]interface {}'`. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

When I make the structures simple enough, they do work, but I need this resource and I'm sure there's a way to do it, and I'm just missing something perhaps trivial.

-- Here's the Terraform structure:

```
resource "struct" "my-struct-1" {
    name = "MyFile"
    complexstruct = [{
        onebool = true
        onearray = [{
            name = "name-1"
            value = "value-1"
        }, {
            name = "name-2"
            value = "value-2"
        }]
        internalstruct = [{
            attr1 = false
            attr2 = "attribute"
        }]
    }]
    array = [
        {
            attrib1 = "attrib1.1"
            attrib2 = false
            attrib3 = "attrib1.3"
        },
        {
            attrib1 = "attrib2.1"
            attrib2 = true
            attrib3 = "attrib2.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

-- Here is the Schema definition in go, as simplified as I could make it:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "name": {
        Type:     schema.TypeString,
        Required: true,
    },
    "complexstruct": {
        Type:   schema.TypeList,
        MaxItems: 1,
        Optional: true,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "onebool": {
                    Type:     schema.TypeBool,
                    Optional: true,
                },
                "onearray": {
                    Type:     schema.TypeList,
                    Optional: true,
                    Elem: &schema.Resource{
                        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                            "name": {
                                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                                Optional: true,
                            },
                            "value": {
                                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                                Optional: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                "internalstruct": {
                    Type:     schema.TypeList,
                    MaxItems: 1,
                    Optional: true,
                    Elem: &schema.Resource{
                        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                            "attr1": {
                                Type:     schema.TypeBool,
                                Optional: true,
                            },
                            "attr2": {
                                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                                Optional: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    "array": {
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Optional: true,
        Elem: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "attrib1": {
                Type: schema.TypeString,
                Optional: true,
            },
            "attrib2": {
                Type: schema.TypeBool,
                Optional: true,
            },
            "attrib3": {
                Type: schema.TypeString,
                Optional: true,
            },
        },
    },
},
```

----- And lastly, here's the code that I am trying to use (however, I think the problem is before it starts with the code itself):

```
fname := d.Get("name").(string)
d.SetId(fname)
if _, ok := d.GetOk("complexstruct"); ok {
    fc := d.Get("complexstruct").([]map[string]interface{})
    myBool := fc[0]["onebool"].(bool)
    myArray := fc[0]["onearray"].([]map[string]interface{})
    type fcS struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Value   string `json:"value"`
    }
    fcs := make([]fcS, len(myArray))
    for ifc := range myArray {
        fcs[ifc].Name = myArray[ifc]["name"].(string)
        fcs[ifc].Value = myArray[ifc]["value"].(string)
    }

    myInternalStruct := fc[0]["internalstruct"].([]map[string]interface{})
    type misS struct {
        Attr1   bool    `json:"attr1"`
        Attr2   string  `json:"attr2"'`
    }
    var mis misS
    mis.Attr1 = myInternalStruct[0]["attr1"].(bool)
    mis.Attr2 = myInternalStruct[0]["attr2"].(string)

    type myWholeStruct struct {
        MyBool      bool        `json:"onebool"`
        MyArray     []fcS       `json:"onearray"`
        MyInter     misS        `json:"internalstruct"`
    }
    outp := myWholeStruct{
        myBool,
        fcs,
        mis,
    }
    o, _ := json.Marshal(outp)
    writeStringToFile(string(o), fname, false)
}
```

Well, I expect the create function to create a file with the name taken from the name attribute, and the data a JSON representation of the values of the other Terraform attributes. Instead I am getting errors as specified above.

Comment: If you look at the docs for the `Elem` field, it says that `it may be either a *Schema or a *Resource`, and a `TypeMap` must be a `*Schema`. This appears to be invalid according the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, @JimB. However, I still don't know how to fix it. If I change the `Elem` to `*Schema`, then I get syntax errors for the field names ("onebool" etc.). If I change it to (what I think the struct really is)  `Elem: map[string]*schema.Schema`, then I get a runtime error `Error: struct.my-struct-1: complexstruct: unexpected map value type: map[string]*schema.Schema{"internalstruct":*schema.Schema{...`. Can you help me formulate it correctly? Thanks a lot

Comment: Still no luck. After the comment from @JimB, I tried to change my `TypeMap` elements to `TypeList` with `MaxItems:1`.  It all compiles nicely, but when running `terraform apply`, I get a panic: `Error reading level config: '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type 'map[string]interface {}'`, and terraform crashes and says "`struct.my-struct-1: unexpected EOF`" (I can't find anything wrong with the HCL itself though).

Comment: what line in your code a panic starts? it is printed in panic stack trace. also you can comment parts of schema to locate where it starts working. just a thought...

Comment: Neither the crash.log nor the stack trace give any indication of a line in my code where the panic starts. Here's an excerpt from the crash.log file: `2019/05/22 21:34:39 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalValidateResource
2019/05/22 21:34:39 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalReadState
2019/05/22 21:34:39 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff
2019-05-22T21:34:39.894+0300 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-struct.exe: panic: Error reading level config: '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type 'map[string]interface {}'`. The panic seems to be inside the Terraform code.

Comment: Thank you all. I worked it through. It was all a matter of casting the right types. It took me a while but I am getting there. Please don't spend any more time on helping me here. Thank you all.

Comment: @Shimon I know it's been a while. Were you able to figure out the solution for this? I am facing the same issue. It would really help if you can post the solution.

Comment: @bitkot, sorry, I never finished this, and anyway I don't have access to the sources any more. Sorry.